# static Invalid block tag inside template file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, python-3.6

I'm having the invalid block tag issue while trying to reference the styles.css file from my app file structure, even having configured everything as the django documentation (and several other answers here in stack overflow) .

I'm using django 2.2.3 in a python3.6 venv along with pureCSS lib.

Here's an overview of my project's files and configuration regarding the templates and the static dir/files:

**1-** settings.py **INSTALLED_APPS** and **STATIC_URL** definition:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pyonlinecourses.core',
]
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**2-** settings.py **TEMPLATES** definitions:

```py
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "pyonlinecourses/core/templates/")
TEMPLATES = [
    {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**3-** Django project directory structure:

```
- pyonlinecourses
  - core
    - migrations
    - static
      - css
    - templates
      - home **(issue located in this file)**
```

**5-** `static` tag definition and reference in html file

```
<!doctype html>
{& load static &}
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="PyOnline Courses - Simple distance education virtual learning environment" />
  <title>PyOnline MOOC</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
</head>
```

I'm at a loss trying to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: Did you set `DEBUG` to `False`?

Comment: No, it's set to `True`, because I'm still developing it

Comment: although not specific to this problem, note that in production, static files are *not* served by Django, you will need to configure nginx/apache to do that.

Comment: I'm aware of that, I've even tried altering the `DEBUG` option before posting the question, and found out about how it should be done in production. But thank you for noting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `{& load static &}` instead of `{% load static %}`.